# Unexpected behavior on elements with transitions in their css

Tags: html, css, positioning, transition

I have written some css for some elements, and it is causing some unexpected behaviour. I am using:

```
transition: 0.2s;
```

When refreshing the page, the element with this css property, unexpectedly start off in another area of the page, and move to their set positions (set in other parts of my css). The,

```
position: absolute
```

property is used to position the elements, what could be causing this unexpected behaviour?

Here is the CSS for the link:

```
.subLinks_links {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.subLinks_links > span {
    margin-left: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
```

}

```
.subLinks_links:hover > span {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

And the relevant HTML for the css:

```
<div id="subLinks">

    <div class="subLinks_links_selected"><span>Link Text</span></div>

    <div class="subLinks_links"><span>Link Text</span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your entire CSS code, and relevant HTML.

Comment: Relevant code has been added.

Comment: @Scimonster - Are you going to help?

Comment: I don't think i can solve this, but now the question is better for other people who might be able to.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it was a positioning issue. I was using text-align and margin-left to position the  elements. There was no dead positioning, which caused the unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm running into a similar issue. You're using the shorthand `transition` property which is actually translating to `transition: all 0.2s ease 0.2s;`. The `all` is important here. This means that the transition you are using for whatever reason (e.g. hover effects, etc.) is also applying itself to other css properties. In this case, the elements are being specifically targeted to change the layout, and since these properties are overriding the defaults there is a transition from the default to your css for every single property that changes.

I know you already found a fix for your case, but this is a possible solution for others who may stumble here later.